# Растянуть кнопки в ряд на всю ширину

Tags: xaml, button, windows-phone-8.1, выравнивание

У меня есть 2 кнопки. Мне необходимо поставить их в один ряд и растянуть на всю ширину экрана. Временное решение такое:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">

     <Button x:Name="Login_Button"
             Content="Войти"
             Margin="0 0 10 0"/>

     <Button x:Name="Offline_Button"
             Content="Offline вход"
             Margin="10 0 0 0"/>

</StackPanel>
```

В данный момент кнопки получают автоматическую ширину и выравниваются по-центру. Необходимо растянуть их до левой и правой границы StackPanel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы выставили ориентацию у StackPanel'и по центру, а это значит, что она будет ужимать весь свой контент до его минимума (по свойству MinWidth у кнопки и прочие параметры, как отступы).
С Grid'ом будет наблюдаться такой же эффект, однако как я заметил StackPanel не умеет "резиновым" образом ограничиваться (по факту она считает, что она безразмерная).

Поэтому я советовал бы переписать этот момент через Grid с колонками. Мой вариант без установки свойства `HorizontalAlignment=Center`. Если это критично, тогда хотел бы видеть более развернутый xaml

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="1"
                Margin="0 0 10 0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        <Button Content="2"
                Margin="10 0 0 0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Очень благодарен за помощь!
С Гридом действительно получилось.
По поводу ориентации по-центру. Теперь это не критично, так как кнопки выглядят от края до края. Раньше стояло выравнивание по центру, так как без него все кнопки выравнивались слева. Как я писал, мера это была запасная, еслиб так и не смог бы растянуть.

Comment: не за что :) можно пометить ответить как правильный)